# Как сделать в асинхронном методе редирект в React-Router v4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Redirect, Switch, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
//import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
//import history from './history';
import { firebaseApp } from './firebase';

import App from './components/App';
import SignIn from './components/SignIn';
import SignUp from './components/SignUp';

let isSignedIn;

firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if(user) {
        console.log('user has signed in or up', user);
        //browserHistory.push('/app');

    } else {
        console.log('user has signed out or still needs to sign in.');
        //browserHistory.replace('/signin');
    }
})

ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter path="/">
    <div>    
        <Switch> 
                <Route path="/app" component={App} />
                <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
                <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />    
        </Switch>   
    </div> 
</BrowserRouter>, 
document.getElementById('root'));
```

Какая есть альтернатива browserHistory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень странно выглядит авторизация у вас, но это ладно. В простейшем случае проблему можно решить так...

```js
class AuthWatcher extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { authState: 'pending' };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      this.setState({ authState: user ? 'done' : 'fail' });
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.authState === 'done') {
      return <Redirect to="/app" />;
    }

    if (this.state.authState === 'fail') {
      return <Redirect to="/signin" />;
    }

    return null;
  }
}

<BrowserRouter path="/">
  <div>
    <AuthWatcher />
      ....
```

Но это не очень аккуратно. Лучше, если вы не используете redux или ещё что-то для управлением состояния, сделать корневой компонент, который рендерит форму авторизации, если её нет, а иначе приложение.

```js
  render() {
    if (this.state.authState === 'done') {
      // лучше вынести в отдельный файл, вроде private-routes.js
      return (
        <Switch> 
          <Route path="/app" component={App} />
        </Switch> 
      );
    }

    if (this.state.authState === 'fail') {
      // лучше вынести в отдельный файл, вроде public-routes.js
      return (
        <Switch> 
          <Route path="/" component={SignIn} />
          <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />    
        </Switch> 
      );
    }

    return <div>Проверка авторизации...</div>;
  }
```

Управлять перенаправлением, к примеру в SignUp после регистрации, оборачивая его в `withRouter` и там будеть history и history.push соответственно.

```js
  import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

  class SignUp extends React.Component {
    signup() {
      request().then(() => this.props.history.push('/'));
    }

  }

  export default withRouter(SignUp);
```

P.S. Не гоняйте пользователя с помощью редиректов по страницам... вы пишите динамическое приложение и нет ничего страшного в том, чтобы показать форму авторизации вместо требуемой страницы, если она нужна и не меняя адрес при этом, это замашки старых приложений, которые рендерились на сервере.